# How to get all addresses that hold a specific SPL token and the token balance during a specific time?

Tags: spl-token, rpc, api

Is there a way to get all addresses with a specific SPL token and its balance during a specific time?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just using the normal Solana JSON RPC API, no. RPC nodes don't normally retain historical snapshots of on-chain data.